# Jquery chosen not working in Dialog, Increasing Dialog area

Tags: jquery

Jquery chosen not working in Dialog, on opening chosen box dialog scroll added automatically. I want chosen container z-indexing above the dialog, it shouldn't go inside of the dialog.

Comment: Please share some code & create fiddle, so that we can help you out.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question accordingly so we can help you